# Custom Tabwidget (Button in Tabwidget)

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-custom-view, tabwidget, fragment-tab-host

[image]

I want to implement this layout with FragmentTabHost, but I don't know what components should I use. I know how to use FragmentTabHost, but in this case there is a round button in the TabWidget.
I know this design doesn't follow the android design principle, but I just want to implement this layout.
Is there any reference about custom View or about how to implement this layout ? 
Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to:

http://www.kpbird.com/2011/05/androidbottom-tabbar-control.html

You can find a source code there with the desired example.

Comment: My button is higher than other tab. But in the example it has the same height.

Comment: The visuals have nothing to do to implementation. You control the visual by setting the desired background to your ui elements, So just make one element's bg bigger. You need to take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html